# Alternative formats for live stream

Tags: nest-device-access

Is there a way to get the live stream in alternative formats other than rtsps?  Very few things seem to support rtsp over ssl, making it almost impossible to actually access the stream.

It would be great if the stream could also be made available as mjpeg over https, or rtsp.

Answer (score 1):

[Gstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/index.html?gi-language=c) i use it for RTSP on android, ios, linux, windows & mac. works for my 4 nest cameras + hello doorbell + hub max.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, only RTSPS is supported. I'd suggest trying with ffmpeg, however you may need to build it from source.

If you're having trouble with ffmpeg, you can modify the ffmpeg source to increase `control_uri` (in `libavformat/rtsp.h`) size from 1024 to 2048, and recompile. Then ffmpeg should be able to play the RTSPS streams.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to FFmpeg? I'm wanting to include the camera stream in a commercial application, and there are licensing issues with FFmpeg that I'm trying to avoid. I'm already using VLCkit but it seems VLC, Quicktime etc are all unable to stream rtsps.